# is it ok or right to downvote an answer just for formatting issues?

Tags: discussion

I just answered a question. And the solution was right. Is it ok to downvote it just because it had some formatting issues ?

Comment: How do you know it was because of formatting issues and not, say, because it was too short? Technically correct /= useful.

Comment: The downvote was accompanied by a comment that downvoting because of formatting issues.

Comment: There was some extra spacing in the code which will have zero effect on the outcome.

Comment: People can downvote for whatever reason they want. But yes formatting and styling are a common reason for downvotes.

Comment: It is **always** ok to downvote. No matter the conditions.

Comment: "This isn't some grade-school essay contest where you get points just for completing the assignment - if your question or _answer_ isn't accessible and understandable by others, it's just noise..." ([Are the Downvoting police too active?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2500/168))

Comment: I think in current shape post is not useful - "formatting issues" may mean a lot of things from missing space after dot to ALL-CAPS to completely invalid in some languages where whitespace is significant... Side note: It's holiday time in many places... so there is very small amount of downvoting going on - when everyone wake up expect more negative attention to "try this"/"it may help" explanations of the code/non-self-documented code-only answers and similar partial content...

Comment: Better would be to 1) edit your question and help you format your answer, or 2) comment to you to improve your formatting up to standards. If going the latter route and no response within a reasonable period of time, then yeah, I'd down-vote.

Comment: @TinyGiant I totally disagree with your comment, most popular though it might seem. It is never ever ok to downvote for a disingenuous reason, such as personal professional advancement ahead of someone else or because you are in a bad mood at the time etc. If you honestly dislike it and you have genuine reasons or even just a 'feeling' like it's a bad question/answer that's different. But if you like or enjoy a question/answer or feel it is useful etc always upvote it. If you're not bothered leave it be.

Comment: @Peter you can do whatever you like with your votes, as long as you aren't voting in a manner that can be considered fraudulent or serial. That is why they are anonymous. Before you get into what the reason behind someone else's downvote is, ask yourself "self, is there any possible way to know why someone downvoted something without a fancy mind reading device?". Undoubtedly, the answer is going to be a resounding "self, no". Vote, or not, for whatever reason you feel applies, if you even care to apply reasoning to your voting.

Comment: I usually consider mind reading to be simply the parsing of meta-data. Like a system of tells. I don't think you need a device, other than your own mind and original senses... The entire cosmos is a network of nodes; though distance and complexity may worry your data, I see no necessary problem with being able to intuit by whom, or why, your post was downvoted. Though perhaps it's a rare skill. In any case I wouldn't personally disingenuously down-vote. Others may get varying millage on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're free to do what you like with your votes, but I personally wouldn't have downvoted for that reason.

The main thing that downvotes are meant to reflect are answer quality.  If the answer is useful, it's *ideal* to upvote it.  You even claim yourself that this answer is correct, but it has a formatting issue.  Just because it's not formatted in a certain way doesn't make it wrong.  It might make it less desirable to look at, but it's not wrong.

The more preferable thing to do in this case would be to *edit* the answer so that its formatting is more presentable.

Again, as I said before, you can vote however you like, but if the answer is right, I don't see why it would be deserving of a downvote.  A bit of spit and polish, sure, but a downvote...

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2500/168

Comment: @gnat:  Personal penchant:  if I can understand the answer *and* make it *more* understandable, simply downvoting isn't constructive.  I feel that I could just edit it into shape.  But I suppose not everyone has the same opinion.